# How to avoid topology errors when digitizing a road network?

Tags: qgis, topology, digitizing

I am working on a road layer project. For the snapping option I'm using the mode to vertex and segment and tolerance 5 pixels. When zooming in (to the max) I do not notice a gap. But when I use the topology checker in QGIS, with the option must not have dangles I notice that there are many dangles (not only on the beginning and end point) of my poly line.
Also I would really like to avoid these type of errors, instead of correcting them in the final phase. 
How  can I  avoid these kind of errors?

Currently I'm using QGIS 2.10.1

Comment: QGIS 2.12 was just released and it has GRASS7 topological digitising support. No idea if it's any better than v6 in 2.10 though.

Comment: Getting same issue with Qgis 2.14.1Essen... I really want to recover from this error....